# Rails 3 + Thinking Sphinx: How to put field weight on Application Wide Search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a `Collection` model and a `Book` model. Collection has a `name` column, while Book has a `title` column. Notice only collection has name, and only book has title.

I'm looking through this: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#fieldweights but the field weights are on one specific model. I need field weights for when I do an application wide search in both Collection and Book using `ThinkingSphinx.search("search term")`.

Am I allowed to put field weights for columns that don't exist in both tables? I want something like `field_weights: {name: 100, title: 1}`. When I try to add that as a second argument for `ThinkingSphinx.search('toy', field_weights: {name: 100, title: 1})` it still doesn't put my collection first. My result classes are still `["Book", "Collection", "Book", "Book", "Book"]`

Perhaps this is the purpose of the `:ranker`?

Comment: I've added the Sphinx tag to this question, as while I know Thinking Sphinx very well (I wrote it), this really comes down to how Sphinx itself behaves, and I'm not sure what the behaviour is when field weights refer to fields that aren't present in _all_ searched indices.

Comment: Great thanks pat. I decided to not merge the two in my search and just do `Collection.search 'search term'` and `Book.search 'search term'`.